# For Hirzebruch Surfaces, does the tangent exact sequence split?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, exact-sequence, tangent-bundle, toric-varieties

Consider the projection $\pi:\mathbb{F}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. Is it true that the following exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow T_{\pi} \rightarrow T_{\mathbb{F}_n} \rightarrow \pi^*T_{\mathbb{P}^1} \rightarrow 0$$ splits? Since $n=0$ case is trivial, I would like to see what happens when $n \ge 1$. I thought there might be some standard source for this but I could not find it on top of my head.

(Edited): I found a way to check it by using brute-force method from toric charts, but would like to find a simple intrinsic way of doing it. For instance, the Ext space for this exact sequence has positive dimension by using Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem on $\mathbb{F}_n$, so what makes tangent bundle correspond to the zero element of the Ext?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: I have no clue.

Comment: I guess the extension class of the tangent bundle sequence for the projectivization of a vector bundle $E$ on a smooth variety $X$ is induced by the traceless part of the Atiyah class of $E$ (I don't know a reference for this, but I am sure this is known). This implies that the extension class of the Hirzebruch surface is nontrivial if $n > 0$.

Comment: Seconded - I find it unbelievable that this gets downvotes. I upvoted it, btw.